# How to install husky-simulator in kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,

I'm new with ros. After having installed ROS kinetic in a blank Ubuntu 16.04 VM (everything very smooth, unbelievable quality of the ROS wiki), I want to try husky-simulator tutorial, as proposed in http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Husky

First step in tutorial is

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-simulator

I get error

> E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-husky-simulator

I understand the package has been created for ROS "indigo" release and since I'm using kinetic it won't work.

Would there be a way to get it working?
Alternatively I may need to replace "kinetic" by "indigo" but I feel it does not scale.

Thank you in advance,
Daniel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256756/how-to-install-husky-simulator-in-kinetic-?/) by [danhilu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29659/danhilu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Credits go to eng/ Esraa Magdy
To install husky on ros kinetic this manuipulation has to be performed

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src   
***%  comment your catkin workspace name here is mine is (catkin_ws)*** 
$ git clone https://github.com/husky/husky.git
$ git clone https://github.com/husky/husky_simulator.git
$ git clone https://github.com/husky/husky_desktop.git

$ cd ..

$ catkin_make
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-multimaster-launch
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-lms1xx
$ rosdep install --from-path src --ignore-src  
$ catkin_make 
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

Now, it's all set up.

2-set the environment variable HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION

```
$ export HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS=$(rospack find husky_description)/urdf/empty.urdf
```

3-Run the simulation environment :

```
$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch
```

or

```
$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Alaa Hesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/33520/alaa-hesham/) with karma: 91 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2018-08-06**:
Thanks for your answer!
After installing the packages, the  rosdep instruction gives me the following error:
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Multiple packages found with the same name "husky_gazebo" and has the packages that are the same in the folders.
Does that mean that I can keep only one?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to previous question

> http://answers.ros.org/question/253648/ros-kinetic-husky-question/

kinetic release for the Husky is being worked on. Consequently  there may be no obvious answer to my question.
I'm now installing ROS Indigo on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM. Everything works fine, Husky is running.

---

Originally posted by [danhilu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29659/danhilu/) with karma: 31 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1